# Mapinfo 15.2 Labeler tool

Tags: labeling, mapinfo

I'm trying to locate labeler tool in MapInfo Pro 15.2, but the tool is missing from the installation folder (I already checked the Program Files(x86) folder as well). There's no trace of it anywhere.

Is it likely that the tool is not included at all in the latest version of MapInfo Pro? Is there any way to locate the MapBasic script for it to create the .mbx?

I'm trying to rotate the labels based on a given column containing angle values (Rotate Symbols function didn't work), and the automatic labeling contained by MapInfo Pro 15.2 doesn't give any option at all to do that for a point layer.

I managed to display it ok with QGIS, but I need a version for MapInfo

Answer (score 3):

We have not ported all the MapBasic applications from 32 bit to 64 bit, yet. That's why you can't find all the applications that you know from the 32 bit version when you are running the 64 bit version.

You can, however, find them in the Tools folder of the 32 bit version, but only if you have the 32 bit installed.

If you don't have the 32 bit version installed, I have shared the Labeler tool here: [Labeler.mbx](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2970888/LABELER.MBX).

When you run the tool in MapInfo Pro 15.2, it will embed itself and it's functions in the Tools window. That's where you will launch its functionality from.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Apparently, the Labeler tool was not much of a help, but I found another solution that works for what I need to do. I have used the help suggestions detailed at the following link (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=da#!topic/mapinfo-l/B3R0xCM3L2w)  I was able to rotate the label this way: creating a line of a specified distance, rotated at a given angle value.

Comment: Ah, right. The Labeler tool doesn't let you rotate the labels. For that you need to RotateLabels tool. But the solution you found above is just as good as it won't create custom labels.